# How can I set my stepper to be at the center

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to align my stepper to be at the center, but it is on the left side. What should I do to align the stepper properly?

[image]

Comment: Try setting the alignment of the stack view to centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While selecting the stack view responsible for your stepper, you may want to check that alignment is set to 'Center' in the attributes inspector. Most likely your alignment for the stack view is left due to the text label above the stepper (but within the stack view. [Attributes Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4bk6.png)

Comment: Didn't notice that option. Thank you @Marmaduk

Answer (score 0):

Replace current stepper with new UIView, and add stepper as sub view of this view